# Pip packages path - windows

Tags: python, windows, path, pip

I have `pip install <package name>` installing the packages to AppData/Python/Python36/Scripts folder. How do I know the exact path to this folder from Command line?

I tried doing `py -m site --userbase` 
This is showing AppData/Roaming/Python/Python36 which does not exist. How will I get to know the path without actually doing manual search?

PS : I am writing an automation script to install pip and awscli later. After I install pip, I face command not found error. So looking how to set path directly from a script without having to face the issue of manually setting it. Found out that pip.exe and aws.exe are under AppData/Python/Python36/Scripts. My question is how do I get this path from inside a script.

Comment: The normal per-user installation directory is `"%LocalAppData%\Programs\Python\PythonXY[-32]"`, and the installer has an option to add this directory plus the "Scripts" subdirectory to `"%PATH%"` (i.e. add Python to environment variables). The installation directory is `sys.prefix`.

Comment: "--user" package installations instead use roaming "%AppData%\Python\PythonXY". I don't recommend using this install option. It was always wrong-headed to use the roaming application data directory to install packages, which may be very large (e.g. scipy). Use virtual environments instead (i.e. `venv`). Maybe in future releases --user can be  changed to use "%LocalAppData%\Programs\PythonXY[-32]" in harmony with the default per-user installation target. Then if you install per user to the default directory, using the --user option with pip would basically be ignored.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here's how to obtain the requested result:

```
python -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print(get_python_lib())"
```

Comment: I have edited my question.Can you please take a look at the edited version.

Comment: Hi there!
I am not sure I 100% understand. 
So you basically want to be able to run pip command from every folder without having errors?

Comment: Yes... The scenario is:
I have python and pip installed. But path is not set to access it from everywhere. So how do I obtain path from batch/bash script commands to set PATH variable it from a script.

Comment: Please check updated version of answer I provided two ways

Comment: I am glad it helped! Can you please share what worked for you so I can edit the answer in order to make it useful for others facing the same issue?

Comment: The last line
 python -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print(get_python_lib())"