# Installed package via pip, but ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, pip, paho

OK so I'm on a windows machine, and wanted to use [paho-mqtt](http://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/python/) package. Downloaded official Python 3 installer msi file, and installed python 3, I don't remember any installation of python before this.

```
>python --version
Python 3.8.1
```

Next, Installed `paho-mqtt` via `pip`

```
>pip install paho-mqtt
Collecting paho-mqtt
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/59/11/.../paho-mqtt-1.5.0.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: paho-mqtt
    Running setup.py install for paho-mqtt ... done
Successfully installed paho-mqtt-1.5.0
```

Tried same command via `pip3` and it says the package is already installed.

But when I `import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt` I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\mqt\paho.py", line 2, in <module>
    import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
  File "C:\mqt\paho.py", line 2, in <module>
    import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'paho.mqtt'; 'paho' is not a package
```

I've done every solution provided online but no chance.

Also got the installation directory using https://stackoverflow.com/a/49028561/2543240 the `paho` directory is there and contains py files.

Is there any debugging command that can help such conditions, to see where is python actually looking for the files it wants to load and can't?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**

Simply `import paho` returns no error. but `import paho.mqtt` leads to

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'paho.mqtt'; 'paho' is not a package`

So installing and uninstalling makes some difference, but just for `import paho` not  `import paho.mqtt` or `import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt`. for the later imports the error message is there whether i install or uninstall paho-mqqt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you name your source file as paho.py, it could hide the paho package.

So renaming paho.py to paho2.py should fix the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Your script `C:\mqt\paho.py` when being run is used by Python import system as **a module** `paho` so `import paho` works but `import paho.mqtt` doesn't because `paho.py` is considered by Python as a module, not a package.

Rename your script. And please remember the experience for the future: never give your scripts the same names as existing modules or packages, especially modules or packages from the standard library. For example, always avoid naming your scripts `email.py` or `test.py`.

Answer (score 1):

You might not be calling the same `python` when you run `pip`.

You can guarantee that you're running pip inside of the correct Python 3.8.1 instance by running:

`python -m pip install paho-mqtt`

Does that help you at all?

Comment: Thanks, but I get `Requirement already satisfied: paho-mqtt in c:\users\...`

Comment: This resolved my problem on Cygwin. Two thumbs up!

Answer (score 0):

You have to mention the version of Python, when normal `pip` is not working.

Install by using `sudo pip3 install paho-mqtt`