# Can not uninstall Tensorflow 2.1.0 as conda can't find the package and solving environment fails

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, anaconda, conda

The tensorflow 2.1.0 package is shown under `conda list` as follows:

[image: conda list output]

But when I try to uninstall it using `conda remove tensorflow` I get the following message:

[image: conda remove output]

`pip uninstall` is also not working. I tried several other methods as well *(shown below)*, and none of these worked. This kinda makes sense as `pip list` *doesn't* show this package.

[image]

*Additional information which is also the strangest thing.* This is how the anaconda navigator shows the package.

[image]

As there are no other packages named as tensorflow present in the list, I assumed that this package  marked in red must be the same tensorflow package which comes up in `conda list`.

Please can someone help me to uninstall this remaining package so that I can have a clean re-installation of the latest tensorflow packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First obtain the path where your packages are installed in anaconda-spyder using this command. Refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49028561/9279666) for more information

```
python -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print(get_python_lib())"
```

Then I was able to find the package that was listed in the final image of the question. So there after it was a matter of deleting those folders shown below.

[image: problematic folders]

After that `conda list` doesn't have that package anymore.

[image]