# Pip error in python when importing modules from pip

Tags: python, pip

When i import modules from pip, like requests i get this error when running in VSCODE:

PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_6yww79s

The only code I used was:
`import requests`

I get the same error if i check pip version in terminal or other commands with pip:
`pip --version`

Full error:

```
PS C:\Script\Frost_met>  & 'C:\Users\jrf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' 'c:\Users\jrf\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.12.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher' '62406' '--' 'c:\Script\Frost_met\frost.py' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jrf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\_common.py", line 89, in _tempfile
    os.write(fd, reader())
  File "C:\Users\jrf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\abc.py", line 371, in read_bytes
    with self.open('rb') as strm:
  File "C:\Users\jrf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\_adapters.py", line 54, in open
    raise ValueError()
ValueError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Script\Frost_met\frost.py", line 4, in <module>
    import requests
  File "C:\Users\jrf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 147, in <module>
    from . import packages, utils
  File "C:\Users\jrf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\utils.py", line 24, in <module>
    from . import certs
  File "C:\Users\jrf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\certs.py", line 14, in <module>
    from certifi import where
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "C:\Users\jrf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\wrapt\importer.py", line 177, in _exec_module
    notify_module_loaded(module)
  File "C:\Users\jrf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\wrapt\decorators.py", line 470, in _synchronized
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jrf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\wrapt\importer.py", line 136, in notify_module_loaded     
    hook(module)
  File "C:\Users\jrf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\certifi_win32\wrapt_certifi.py", line 20, in apply_patches
    certifi_win32.wincerts.CERTIFI_PEM = certifi.where()
  File "C:\Users\jrf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\certifi\core.py", line 37, in where
    _CACERT_PATH = str(_CACERT_CTX.__enter__())
  File "C:\Users\jrf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\contextlib.py", line 135, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\jrf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\_common.py", line 95, in _tempfile
    os.remove(raw_path)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\Users\\jrf\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp23ldltgt'
PS C:\Script\Frost_met>
PS C:\Script\Frost_met>  & 'C:\Users\jrf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' 'c:\Users\jrf\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.12.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher' '62406' '--' 'c:\Script\Frost_met\frost.py' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jrf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\_common.py", line 89, in _tempfile
    os.write(fd, reader())
  File "C:\Users\jrf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\abc.py", line 371, in read_bytes
    with self.open('rb') as strm:
  File "C:\Users\jrf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\_adapters.py", line 54, in open
    raise ValueError()
ValueError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Script\Frost_met\frost.py", line 4, in <module>
    import requests
  File "C:\Users\jrf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 147, in <module>
    from . import packages, utils
  File "C:\Users\jrf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\utils.py", line 24, in <module>
    from . import certs
  File "C:\Users\jrf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\certs.py", line 14, in <module>
    from certifi import where
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "C:\Users\jrf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\wrapt\importer.py", line 177, in _exec_module
    notify_module_loaded(module)
  File "C:\Users\jrf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\wrapt\decorators.py", line 470, in _synchronized
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jrf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\wrapt\importer.py", line 136, in notify_module_loaded     
    hook(module)
  File "C:\Users\jrf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\certifi_win32\wrapt_certifi.py", line 20, in apply_patches
    certifi_win32.wincerts.CERTIFI_PEM = certifi.where()
  File "C:\Users\jrf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\certifi\core.py", line 37, in where
    _CACERT_PATH = str(_CACERT_CTX.__enter__())
  File "C:\Users\jrf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\contextlib.py", line 135, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\jrf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\_common.py", line 95, in _tempfile
    os.remove(raw_path)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\Users\\jrf\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp23ldltgt'
PS C:\Script\Frost_met>
```

Comment: are you sure you are not still running another instance of the code?

Comment: Just restarted to be sure :S

Comment: Is the file or folder accessible, has it any encryption on it? Also is this the full error message?

Comment: I  added the full error to the description now.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the problem comes from python-certifi-win32, as seen in the error messages. To solve it use the link below there are solutions for python-certifi-win32 problem.

[python-certifi-win32 problem with solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71987695/pip-is-broken-gives-permissionerror-winerror-32)

If these solutions don't work search for python-certifi-win32 uninstall and install process.
Last but not recommended solution uninstall all python files and libraries delete config files, caches and all files related to python and reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same problem, but the error was intermittent. If you are coding your file open/close correctly and still running into this error, make sure you are not synching the files with Dropbox, Google Drive, etc. I paused Dropbox and I no longer see the error.

Comment: Thanks. I tried stopping my internet connection, but I get the same error. I got my python scripts located on my C folder and newer had this problem before :S